# How much nude material is available in free roam after the game's ending?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Free roam after ending in The Witcher 3 is pretty empty - not much monster to fight, the forest, cave, and even monster den is so empty, can't beat civilians, can't chop off the head of solders, But I wonder if I can still see nudity in free roam.

I see that in free roam after the ending, you can still visit brothels, but is that all? Can I still see [succubi](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Succubus) or [the characters](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_3:_Wild_Hunt_-_Guide_to_Romance) whom I saw before?

How much nudity can still be seen in free roam after ending?

Comment: This question doesn't quite sit right with me; I'm not sure it belongs here on Arqade, and judging from the votes I don't think I'm alone in this assessment. However, I have edited it to remove vulgarity in accordance with the [Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy: *"**Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"* - try to keep this policy in mind when phrasing questions in the future.

Comment: Did you finish the [Iron Maiden](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Maiden) quest on Faroe Island? Also, the Blood&Wine has some of that content, including a whole new brothel ;)

Comment: Thank @SF, cool quest, the game said about marriage & have children with that Iron Maiden, but I guess we can't "hang out" with her after the quest, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The free roam mode after the ending is there to give you a chance to experience side quests you couldn't or didn't complete before the game ending, to start the expansion content of Hearts of Stone and Blood & Wine and to explore areas you haven't visited as well as partake in the repeatable activities (e.g. Gwent).

It seems you are looking for additional content, which is unlocked after finishing the game. There is none, technically you can even play the expansion content before completing the main storyline.

Nudity scenes aren't repeatable activities, except for brothel visits.

Comment: So it's also confirmed that there is no succubi either, right?

Comment: @123iamking Succubi only appear as part of certain quests. Once you completed those, you won't see any more.